# How to insert round brackets in mysql table using AWK script?

Tags: mysql, awk

I have created a table with two integer columns and wanted to insert square of each number in the table. The output should be like this..

> (1,1)
>   (2,4)

AWK script for creating database table...

```
BEGIN {
    system("echo 'create table square (col1 INT, col2 INT);' | mysql -u root -D database")
   }
```

I want to display the output with brackets and commas into two integer columns and want to write the AWK script to insert the data into the above table
This is my AWK script.

```
BEGIN {
for (i=1; i<=10; i++)
print "(" i "," i*i ")";
}
```

Comment: `print "insert into square (" i ", " i*i ");"` would work in some databases. If this is not your intent, then your question is unclear. Good luck!

Comment: HI Shellter, I will give a try and revert you back. I appreciate your efforts. Thanks alot.

Comment: Hi Shellter, this didn't worked..I have tried like this with the AWK script! for (i=1;i<=10;i++) { system ("echo 'insert into square SET id=i, id2=i*i;' | mysql -u root -D database") }

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot the "values" key before the bracket??

```
echo "line" > file.dat
awk 'BEGIN{
    system("echo 'create table square (col1 INT, col2 INT);' | mysql -u root -D database")
    for (i=1; i<=10; i++)
    {
        print " insert into square values (" i "," i*i ");"
    }
}' file.dat > querys.sql
```

cat querys.sql

the insert into SQL method is suposed to have the values key http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

**EDIT** some improvements to make it in just one command:

```
> file.dat
> querys.sql 
awk 'BEGIN{
    system("echo \"create table square (col1 INT, col2 INT);\" | mysql -u root -D database")
        for (i=1; i<=10; i++)
        {
            print " insert into square values (" i "," i*i ");" >> "querys.sql"
        }
    }

END{
system("mysql -u root -D database < querys.sql")
}' file.dat
```

Hope it helps

Comment: always 4 eyes see more than 2 :)  Thanks!! hope it helped!!

Comment: While your system should work (with `system(...)` calls), standard practice would be to do as much as possible from the `shell` layer, using pipes and other redirections as you have done, but without the extra layer inside of `awk`. Good luck to all!

Comment: completely ok with that. Just coded that way to show the OP the "in-awk" option :) thanks!!!!  maybe tomorrow will add an edit with a shell + awk solution. Now going to sleep. It´s too late here! bye!!